# OpenVINO library does not see Neural Compute stick 2 on Raspberry pi 4

Tags: python, raspberry-pi4, openvino

I used [this](https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/openvino_docs_install_guides_installing_openvino_raspbian.html) guide to install the openVINO toolkit on my Raspberry pi 4 model B. And [this](https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/openvino_docs_install_guides_configurations_for_ncs2.html) to perform inference on Neural Compute Stick 2.

But then when I tried to look at the available devices using the openvino library:

```
import openvino.inference_engine as ie
engine = ie.IECore()
print(engine.available_devices)
```

It shows:

`['CPU']`
But it also had to output 'MYRIAD'

In `lsusb` i see my device:
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 03e7:2485 Intel Movidius MyriadX

How can I fix this?

I tried reinstalling other versions of Raspbian OS 64 bit but it didn't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Debian packages listed in [storage.intel.com](https://storage.openvinotoolkit.org/repositories/openvino/packages/2022.3/linux/) do not include Myriad plugin (*libopenvino_intel_myriad_plugin.so*) needed to inference on Neural Compute Stick 2, they only include the CPU plugin for ARM CPU. You can verify this by listing the *path-to/l_openvino_toolkit_debian9_2022.3.0.9052.9752fafe8eb_arm64/runtime/lib/aarch64* directory and see *libopenvino_intel_myriad_plugin.so* missing:

[image: list directory _openvino_toolkit_debian9_2022.3.0.9052.9752fafe8eb_arm64/runtime/lib/aarch64]

One of the alternatives to get the Myriad plugin on Raspbian is to build OpenVINO from source using 2022.1 branch. You can achieve this by following the instructions outlined in documentation. Here are some resources to help with this alternative:

- [Build for Raspbian Stretch* OS](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/openvino/wiki/BuildingForRaspbianStretchOS)
- [Building Open Source OpenVINO™ toolkit for Raspbian* OS and Intel® Neural Compute Stick 2](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000057005/boards-and-kits.html)